# What is the difference between K-Means & Self Organized Maps?

Tags: clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning

It seems they both perform clustering. They both reduce the dimensionality of the input data and classify further inputs based upon their distance/similarity to the center points. These points then update to accommodate the new data.

I am yet to understand how these two methods are different. I suppose it depends on the problem to be solved. How could each be suited to different problems (advantages/disadvantages)?

Comment: What do they have in common except computing distances? In fact, SOMs are often used as a step *before* k-means, because SOMs do not produce clusters (instead, you run k-means on the mapped data - SOM itself is *not* a clustering algorithm!).

Answer (score 0):

[Self-organizing map (SOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map) is a dimensional reduction technique that learns a reduced feature mapping.

Clustering groups individual instances together.

Dimensional reduction and clustering are fundamentally different processes.